# How come this reduce method doesn't give me object back?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`[['id', '1111'], ['name', 'aaaaa']]`

I have a list like this.

`{ id: '1111', name: 'aaaa' }`

And, I want to format the list to something like this.

So, I've tried to convert the list to the object in that format with reduce method of JavaScript like the below.

But, it doesn't work!

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it, please?

## Code

```
const result = [['id', '1111'], ['name', 'aaaaa']].reduce(
    (accumulator, list, index) => {
        const KEY = list[0];
        const VALUE = list[1];

        console.log(accumulator)

        if(KEY === 'id' || KEY === 'name') {
            return accumulator[KEY] = VALUE;
        }

        return accumulator

    },
    {
        id: '',
        name: ''
    }
);
```

## log from the console.log(accumulator)

```
{ id: '', name: '' }
1111 // why this is not { id: '1111', name: '' } ???
```

## Expected Result

```
{ id: '1111', name: 'aaaa' }
```

Comment: Remove the `return` that's inside your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only return  once. In the conditional only set the property

```
if(KEY === 'id' || KEY === 'name') {
   /*return*/ accumulator[KEY] = VALUE;
   // ^^ remove the return
}
```

You aren't returning the full object otherwise

Answer (score 2):

You should return `accumulator` in reduce callback, but the result of `accumulator[KEY] = VALUE` statement is not `accmulator`, so remove `return` key word in the if clause:

```
if(KEY === 'id' || KEY === 'name') {
    accumulator[KEY] = VALUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is returning the value...remove the return statement.

```
    if(KEY === 'id' || KEY === 'name') {
        return accumulator[KEY] = VALUE;
    }
```

To

```
    if(KEY === 'id' || KEY === 'name') {
         accumulator[KEY] = VALUE;
    }
```